# Visual Studio 2013 claiming it can't and can find a class simultaneously

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Visual Studio seems to enjoy making things up as it goes. For its newest trick, it is telling me that it cannot find some class..

"The type or namespace name 'SomeClass' does not exist in the namespace 'This.That' (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Which is quite silly because the line that has this error, I can simply click where I'm trying to instantiate an object of 'SomeClass', and click Go To Definition. Surprise surprise, Visual Studio knows EXACTLY where the class is located. The project is built, the assemblies are sitting there.

How can I tell VS to grow up/realize it knows where the class is?

I should note this error was caused by closing VS and opening it again.

Edit: I should also note that I can target the class directly

```
this.that.SomeClass();
```

Visual Studio also knows all about what's inside 'that', including both classes I am pointing it at.

I've done everything obvious at this point, cleaned all the projects, deleted .suo files, rebooted, attempted building in different ways.

Answer (score 0):

VS does occasionally get out of sync.  This is an extremely obvious response and I assume you have already done this, but cleaning and rebuilding will occasionally get it back into a valid state.  Also check that the references in the "references" pseudo-folder for this dll do not have a warning or "can't find" marking.

Comment: Unfortunately I've deleted .suo files, cleaned multiple times, rebooted, and attempted building in various ways. VS really cannot figure its life out.